# BiqQuery insert retry policy in Apache Beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam

Apache Beam API has the following BiqQuery insert retry policies.

- How Dataflow job behave if I specify *retryTransientErrors*?
- *shouldRetry* provides an error from BigQuery and I can decide if I should retry. Where can I find expected error from BigQuery?

**BiqQuery insert retry policies**

https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/InsertRetryPolicy.html

- alwaysRetry - Always retry all failures.
- neverRetry - Never retry any failures.
- retryTransientErrors - Retry all failures except for known persistent errors.
- shouldRetry - Return true if this failure should be retried.

**Background**

- When my Cloud Dataflow job inserting very old timestamp (more than 1 year before from now) to BigQuery, I got the following error.

```
 jsonPayload: {
  exception:  "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Insert failed:
 [{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"","location":"","message":"Value 690000000 for field
 timestamp_scanned of the destination table fr-prd-datalake:rfid_raw.store_epc_transactions_cr_uqjp is outside the allowed bounds.
You can only stream to date range within 365 days in the past and 183 days in
the future relative to the current date.","reason":"invalid"}],
```

- After the first error, Dataflow try to retry insert and it always rejected from BigQuery with the same error.
- It did not stop so I added *retryTransientErrors* to BigQueryIO.Write step then the retry stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How Dataflow job behave if I specify retryTransientErrors?

All errors are considered transient except if BigQuery says that the error reason is one of ["invalid", "invalidQuery", "notImplemented"](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/c2f0d282337f3ae0196a7717712396a5a41fdde1/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/InsertRetryPolicy.java#L44)

> shouldRetry provides an error from BigQuery and I can decide if I should retry. Where can I find expected error from BigQuery?

You can't since the errors are [not visible](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/c2f0d282337f3ae0196a7717712396a5a41fdde1/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/InsertRetryPolicy.java#L36) to the caller. I'm not sure if this was done on purpose or whether Apache Beam should expose the errors so users can write their own retry logic.